# Handling response object after POST

Tags: jquery, django

I'm working with django, and trying to retrieve a list via POST, sent by jQuery.

The post code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url:'/coupons/sideContentCoupons/',
    success: function(data){
        // access response and retrieve data.
    }
});
```

The handler:

```
def sideContentCoupons(request):
    response = HttpResponse("", None, 200, "")
    response['field'] = "data"
    return response
```

This is a basic attempt to access the 'field', but I can't get the "data".

How can I access the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of what you want to do is a bit confused, but if I understand correctly, it's sending from Django to jQuery via Ajax, and accessing the data there, that you're asking about.

If so, you should probably think about sending your data as JSON.

```
def handler(request):
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'field': 'data'}))


$.getJSON('/coupons/sideContentCoupons/',
    function(data) {
        alert(data['field']);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the data because your not sending any.

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: //this can either be a query string eg. foo=bar&bar=foo or an object
          // {foo:'bar', bar:'foo'}
    url:'/coupons/sideContentCoupons/',
    success: function(data){
        // access response and retrieve data.
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't need to send any data to the handler, I just need to handle the data that it returns in the response